# Is there any method in Triggers to skip update/insert from particular user in DB2?

Tags: sql, database, triggers, db2

I don't have much knowledge in TRIGGERS, below is my doubt kindly suggest any answers.

SYSTEM:
I have a table called A with Triggers, it designed in such a way if any update/insert happens it will update/insert the same in Table B.

PROCESS:
Table A will get updated by multiple users

MY QUESTION:
I want to block one user/Batch JOB. i.e. if any update/insert is performed by this user/BatchJob in TABLE A, it wont be propagated to  Table B.

IS it possible in DB2 Triggers? If so Please Help me. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a new table to your DB that contains users you want to block (or add a column to an existing user table).

Then change your trigger like this

```
if current_user is not in blocked_user_table
then
    insert in table b
end
```